# Can I create an LLC, offshore, or a Limited company in the the U.K. to invest my personal money in equities?

Tags: taxes, investing, united-kingdom, limited-liability-company, law

So, I have a large portfolio of stock assets, gold etc. and I want to leave these specific assets from some of my brokers and physical gold/silver to one of my grandchildren, 14 (please don't tell me he is too young to take control of this etc. when he is 16/18) and I wish to set up a way for him to take control of these assets when he is 18, I have full trust that he can, so I was thinking of setting up a company, probably a Limited U.K. company or an offshore LLC, which he owns 100% equity in and I the director, until he is 18, so in case I die before he is 16 (minimum director age), the assets do not have to go through a trust etc. to reach him.

Aside from tax inefficiencies, what would be the limitations to do this? Also, can I transfer public stock I own personally to the company?
Also, can the company transfer the stock owned in the company's name to a different company, if needed?

And, what would be the company type? Would it have to be a special type of investment company? Or could it be set up as a general holding company, that I could transfer property to as well, for my grandchild to receive?
I was thinking of injecting capital through a bond/bonds, with terms set so that the debt can be repayable on demand, and when he is 18, or in my will, leaving the bond(s) to him so he can access the capital as well, but he still owns 100% equity, so he would be able to pay dividends anyway, and avoid inheritance tax as he would already own the stock in the company.

Comment: This is a great wall of text with many, unfocused questions. As far as I can tell of what you want to do – and admittedly with only a general knowledge of trusts –  a trust of some kind would seem the obvious first-choice, so as well as explaining clearly what you want to achieve, it would help to explain why you don't want to use a trust.

Comment: It does sound like you need both legal and tax advice. There are a lot of factors here and it seems you aren't 100% decided on what you want to achieve with this, other than it being a scheme to avoid Inheritance Tax. See https://www.gov.uk/guidance/tax-avoidance-an-introduction

Comment: Welcome new user.  While a great question it is probably "too broad" and "too many questions at once" for anyone here to help.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm going to suggest might do the job but might not.

"I wish to set up a way for him to take control of these assets when he is 18"

"so in case I die before he is 16 (minimum director age), the assets do not have to go through a trust etc. to reach him."

Both of these can be met by using a **Junior ISA**. These are tax-sheltered accounts like adult ISAs, and indeed when the child reaches 18 that's what they automatically become. Things are different in one important respect: normally(*), **no withdrawals can take place while the child is still a child**. Not by anyone. So even if the original donor of the funds dies, the money is still the child's.

One factor that might be a problem for you is that the setup and management of a JISA can only be done by the child's parent / legal guardian. Anyone can put money in, but only that registered contact can decide what it's invested in.

Also, depending on what you mean by "large portfolio", the **annual contribution limit of £9k** (as of 2020-1 tax year) might or might not be a problem for you. If you've got a lot more than this, then really **trusts** are what you want, and you'd have to explain what your problem with them is. One might argue that if you've got that much capital, then paying for an actual professional shouldn't be a problem...

<sub>(*) exceptions only in cases like the terminal illness or death of the child</sub>